# Getting Json response in Spring MVC using pebble template

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, thymeleaf, spring-restcontroller

I'm using pebble template for my Spring MVC application. Is there a way to return JSON response object back instead of HTML template to the client for a particular API call?

When I try to send the JSON object I'm getting the following exception.

```
com.mitchellbosecke.pebble.error.LoaderException: Could not find template "templates/test/1.html" (?:?)
        at com.mitchellbosecke.pebble.loader.ClasspathLoader.getReader(ClasspathLoader.java:74)
        at com.mitchellbosecke.pebble.loader.ClasspathLoader.getReader(ClasspathLoader.java:26)
....
....
```

```
Caused by 
org.springframework.web.HttpMediaTypeNotAcceptableException: Could not find acceptable representation
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I just needed to add `@ResponseBody` in my method and that fixed the issue.